# Can't push to main on new git repo

Tags: git, github

I am realtivly new to git and have created a new github repo after the update which switched master to main.

The first problem I had was that when I pulled `git pull origin main` nothing came down. At the time the repo continued a .gitignore, readme, and a licence. I solved this by manually downloading them.

However, I am unable to push to main. When I tried to run `git push origin main` I got an error message and was told by git to run the following: `git push --set-upstream origin master`. After running that, I can now push to master but not main. When I try to run `git push origin main` I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Ebony-Ayers/CS-style-text-format'
```

How can I make it so that I can push to main rather than master as according to the repo on the github website main is my default branch?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What is your local branch called? `git push origin main` tries to take your local branch called `main` and pushes it to `origin`. If you do not have a local branch called `main`, then git won't be able to push anything, which seems to be why you are receiving this error. What you can do is run the following:

```
git checkout -b main
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

and this should correct the issue.

To break down what's happening:

```
git checkout -b main
```

This command creates a new local branch called `main`. It is identical to the branch that you are working off of (I'm assuming `master`). You can check what branch you are on either by running `git status` and in the several lines that are printed the branch name should show, or more clearly `git branch` which will list all local branches but highlight the current branch you are on. When creating a new branch, any local changes (whether staged or unstaged) are also maintained and not removed from the working directory.

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

This command pushes to `origin`, which is the name of the remote repository on GitHub, and pushes your local branch `main`, which we created above. This will create a new branch in GitHub with the same name as well, and the `--set-upstream` flag tells git that `origin main` is the default remote/branch combo that you want to push to, and you can simply run `git push` and it will by default push any local changes on `main`

Once the new `main` branch is pushed, and you confirm that everything is there as expected, you should be able to delete the `master` branch directly from GitHub. You can also delete the branch locally by running:

```
git branch -D master
```

Make sure not to delete either the local or the remote `master` branch until you have confirmed that everything you need is in the new `main` branch. This should not be the case, but it never hurts to double check.

Comment: I tried ```git push --set-upstream origin main``` and I didn't work

Comment: What was the error? Do you have a local branch `main`?

Comment: I deleted the entire repository (after backing up the code) and recreated it and did all the local set up steps again and now I works. Thanks For the help.

Comment: Sidenote, why has this changed because back when master was the default I didn't have to set the upstream for each now repo?

Comment: In my limited experience, I have always had to configure `--set-upstream` if I wanted to set the default `git push` remote and branch, even when `master` was the default. This way, rather than always running `git push origin main`, I could just run `git push`. If I wanted to push to a different remote or a different branch, then I could specify both remote and branch as well.

Comment: All this trouble because of politically correct Silicon Valley manager decided that Github should change the default branch from master to main... unbelievable.

Comment: Does git init makes a default master branch?

Comment: @piyush172 `git init` just initializes the folder in question with the necessary config files. When you run that command in a folder, you will see a `.git` folder where these are stored (files/folders that start with `.` are usually hidden so you may not see them initially in the file explorer). There are no branches that are created. When creating a repo in GitHub (not sure about other git-based hosts), it creates a default branch. Up until recently, I cant remember exactly when, this branch was called `master`. It is now called `main`.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to push your local repo to remote in GitHub but your local repo branch is named  `'master'` and your remote is named `'main'` you wont be able to push.

The solution as described by GitHub documentation is to rename your local repo to `'main'`.

To do this your current branch needs to `'master'`
Verify your branch using command :

```
git branch
```

this will list all branches and highlight your current branch.

Then to rename the branch the command is :

```
git branch -M main
```

The flag `-M` is a shortcut for flags : `--move --force`.
The `move` means move/rename a branch, together with its config and reflog.

Additionally, as commented by *(#Sal from Dec 24, 2020 at 8:20)*  for convenience you can set `'main'` as the default branch with:

```
 git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Once `'main'` is default then you can just do `git push` or `git pull` without adding the branch name to the command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

You can't push from master -> main, repo names must be the same. so to first rename your local git repository

```
git branch -m master main
```

Next rebase your both branches (local and remote)

```
git pull --rebase origin main
```

and then push

```
git push -u origin main
```